# How to estimate ERC721 mint transaction?

Tags: gas-estimate, erc-721

My contract;

```
contract My721 is ERC721Full, ERC721Mintable, Ownable {

    constructor() ERC721Full("My721", "MY721") public {}

    function mintUniqueTokenTo (address _to, uint256 _tokenId, string  _tokenURI) public{        
        super.mint(_to, _tokenId);        
        super._setTokenURI(_tokenId, _tokenURI);
    }
}
```

I tried to run my own node script;

```
my721Instance.methods.mintUniqueTokenTo(...)
    .estimateGas()
    .then(function(estimate) {
        console.log("Estimated Gas Consumptions: ", estimate);           
});
```

I got;

```
(node:27428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: my721Instance.methods.mintUniqueTokenTo is not a function
```

Fyi, I successfully ran the transaction in truffle console. Any idea?

Comment: As the error says, `my721Instance.methods.mintUniqueTokenTo` is not a function. If that's unexpected to you and you need help figuring out why that happened, you'll need to share the code that defines `my721Instance`.

Comment: I used openzeppelin-solidity library to code My721 contract as shown above. I also checked the My721.json and console.log(my721Instance.methods). And yes there is mintUniqueTokenTo function. Also the function works but when I tried to use with estimateGas() it gave the error.

Comment: The error is in JavaScript, so the Solidity code is irrelevant. You claim that `my721Instance.methods.mintUniqueTokenTo` is a function, but the JavaScript interpreter believe differently. You need to figure it why there's a discrepancy. (I can't help without code.)

Answer (score 2):

Following is a complete test which you can replicate using Node on your development machine. This test will require access to a web3 provider. I am using Infura which you will a password to use.

The `mint` function is not part of [the ERC-721 standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) but there is an example of a `mint` implementation in the [ERC-721 reference implementation](https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721).

## Dependencies

Install this minimal file as `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@0xcert/ethereum-erc721": "^2.0.0-rc1",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36"
  }
}
```

Then run `npm install`.

Note: recent versions of Web3 have various issues. The code below was tested and confirmed working with version ^1.0.0-beta.36.

## Test suite

Install this file as `estimate.js`:

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/' + INFURA_PASSWORD));

// Test specimen
const nftAddr = '0xd8bbf8ceb445de814fb47547436b3cfeecadd4ec'; // https://github.com/0xcert/ethereum-erc721#playground
const nftArtifacts = require("@0xcert/ethereum-erc721/build/nf-token-mock.json"); // Standards compliant implementation plus publicly accessible mint & burn
const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(nftArtifacts.NFTokenMock.abi, nftAddr);

// Test parameters
const randomEthereumAddress = nftAddr; // TODO: improve this
const randomTokenID = 42; // TODO: improve this

// Test procedure
nftContract.methods
  .mint(randomEthereumAddress, randomTokenID)
  .estimateGas()
  .then(function (estimate) {
    console.log("Estimated gas to execute mint: ", estimate);
  });
```

Now you may perform the test case by running `npm estimate.js`.

> Estimated gas to execute mint:  66791

## Discussion

Your estimate gas test will return a different gas value if you use a different implementation of the non-fungible token contract or if certain circumstances change on your network (all deployed code and storage). Following are some particular circumstances to check:

- Does the `mint` recipient already own any tokens? *This matters with `ERC721Enumerable`.*
- Was this token ID already minted?
- Does your `mint` implementation call `onERC721Received` on the recipient?
- If it does call, does the recipient throw?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my node script ("check.js"):

```
require("dotenv").config();
const Web3 = require("web3");
var fs = require("fs"); // File stream
var csv = require("fast-csv");
var Papa = require("papaparse");
var BigNumber = require("bignumber.js");
const chalk = require("chalk");
const chalkerror = chalk.bold.red;

// NFT
const nftArtifacts = require("../build/contracts/My721.json");
const contract = require("truffle-contract");
var nftContract = contract(nftArtifacts);

var IPFS = require("ipfs-mini");
var orgPath = process.env.npm_config_org;
var nftAddr = process.env.npm_config_nft;

const ipfs = new IPFS({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 5001,
  protocol: "http"
});

if (typeof web3 !== "undefined") {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  console.log("web3 connect to current provider");
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
  console.log("web3 connected to: ", web3._requestManager.provider.host);
}

//Instantiate nft at an address
var nft;
var coinbase;
nftContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
nftContract.at(nftAddr).then(function(_instance) {
    nft = _instance;
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(async (_accounts, error) => {
        coinbase = _accounts[0];
        var isMinter = await nft.isMinter(coinbase);
        if (!isMinter) {
            console.log(
                chalkerror(`You ${coinbase} is not a minter. aridrop will exit.`)
            );
            process.exit(0);
        }
        var nftName = await nft.name();
        var nftSymbol = await nft.symbol();

        nft.methods
            .mintUniqueTokenTo(_accounts[1], 10, "DummyURI", {
                from: coinbase
            })
            .estimateGas()
            .then(function(estimate) {
                console.log("Estimated Gas Consumptions: ", estimate);
                requiredGas = estimate;
            });
});

module.exports.cost = function() {
    var index = 0;
    var validIndex = 0;
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(`data/${orgPath}/receipients.csv`);
    var csvStream = csv()
    .on("data", function(data) {
        index++;
    })
    .on("end", function() {
        console.log(chalk.yellow(`Receipient count: ${index}`));
        if (validIndex == 0) {
            console.log(`Great! All addresses are valid!`);
        } else {
            console.log(chalkerror(`There is invalid receipient address.`));
            console.log(
                chalkerror(
                    `Please refer data/${orgPath}/invalid.csv file for list of 
                     invalid addresses.`
           )
        );
    }
});
    stream.pipe(csvStream);
};
```

the "script" section in the package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "lite-server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "check": "node -e 'require(\"./scripts/2_check\").check()'"
},
```